# Integrate EWZRecaptchaBundle on symfony framework

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.0

I try to integrate the `EWZRecaptchaBundle` to my site (based on the symfony framework) but this exception prevents me from completing my job. I don't know the problem.

```
Fatal error: Declaration of EWZ\Bundle\RecaptchaBundle\Form\Type\RecaptchaType::
buildView() must be compatible with that of Symfony\Component\Form\FormTypeInterface::
buildView() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/AgencePublicite/vendor/excelwebzone/recaptcha-bundle/EWZ/Bundle/RecaptchaBundle/Form/Type/RecaptchaType.php on line 147
```

Comment: Incompatible versions! Told you, but [you wouldn't listen!](http://www.siteduzero.com/forum-83-805474-p1-integration-ewzrecaptchabundle-symphony2.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using 2.0 version of symfony you shouldn't get master version , but the 2.0 tagged one. However I didnt bother to use a bundle for recaptcha, but this bundle seems very complete as it supports even custom templates.

Answer (score 0):

for me, the master version works with symfony 2.1.0 in this point.
but the recaptcha didn`t validate and i got a "This form should not contain extra fields" as mentioed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14263184/symfony2-ewzrecaptchabundle-extra-fields)