# symfony2 EWZRecaptchaBundle extra Fields

Tags: symfony, recaptcha

I have a problem with the EWZRecaptcha Bunlde (dev-master) and symfony 2.1.0.
The reCaptcha is displayed correctly and the image changes so i think the configuration is ok. But the reCaptcha is not validated and after submitting, `$form->getErrorsAsString()` says: This form should not contain extra fields.

Well, i think the extra fields are `recaptcha_challenge_field` and `recaptcha_response_field` that are sent from reCaptcha but i don think that i missed something in [the docu](https://github.com/excelwebzone/EWZRecaptchaBundle) so what can be wrong with them?

For validation i use the code from [the docu](https://github.com/excelwebzone/EWZRecaptchaBundle): (i also tried the alternative, that was mentioned there)

```
use EWZ\Bundle\RecaptchaBundle\Validator\Constraints as Recaptcha;
//...
/**
* @Recaptcha\True
*/
public $recaptcha;
//...
```

in config:

```
framework:
    validation: { enable_annotations: true }
```

i added the field like this:

```
$builder->add('recaptcha', 'ewz_recaptcha', array(
                'property_path' => false,
                'attr' => array(
                    'options' => array(
                        'theme' => 'clean'
                    )
                )
));
```

Maybe i forgot something essential, that was not mentioned in the docu?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly try adding a 'constraints' option to the builder.  My recaptcha builder add looks like this:

```
    $builder->add('recaptcha', 'ewz_recaptcha', array(
                        'attr'          => array(
                            'options' => array(
                                'theme' => 'red'
                            )
                        ),
                        'label' => "Verification",
                        'property_path' => false,
                        'constraints'   => array(
                            new True()
                        ),
                        'help' => "Enter the words in the box for verification purposes."
                    ));
```

So add a 'use' statement for the constraint:

```
use EWZ\Bundle\RecaptchaBundle\Validator\Constraints\True;
```

and then add the constraint option:

```
'constraints'   => array(
    new True()
),
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. As mentioned i've also tried this way. No luck. By the way the option "help" does not exist. Which symfony version do you use?

Comment: The whole error-message is: `form: ERROR: This form should not contain extra fields. recaptcha: No errors !`

Comment: `$builder->add('recaptcha_challenge_field', 'hidden', array('property_path' => false));
$builder->add('recaptcha_response_field', 'hidden', array('property_path' => false));`

Comment: Did that work for you?  My form does not require those fields.

Answer (score 0):

finally found the solution!
to get rid of the `extra fields` i added those two fields in my form class:

```
$builder->add('recaptcha_challenge_field', 'hidden', array('property_path' => false));
$builder->add('recaptcha_response_field', 'hidden', array('property_path' => false));
```

the validation then works with:

```
use EWZ\Bundle\RecaptchaBundle\Validator\Constraints\True;
...
'constraints'   => array(
                    new True()
                )
```

the annotation **doesn`t** work for me:

```
use EWZ\Bundle\RecaptchaBundle\Validator\Constraints AS Recaptcha;
...
/**
 * @Recaptcha\True
 */
public $recaptcha;
```